# Android , How to add additional permission in new facebook Graph API v 2.3?

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-access-token, facebook-authentication

I want to add new permission to my app by new Facebook Graph API v2.3 but I cannot find any useful resource in Internet.

Answer (score 0):

You can ask for some additional permissions like this:
 Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(
                activity, Arrays.asList("email", "user_birthday", "user_location"));
        session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);